# Fetch json data UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking

I'm trying to fetch json data from UIViewcontroller in objective-c.But it's not change anything in view.

what should I do ?

```
- (void)api {
    NSLog(@"test");
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/api/index.php"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"musteri_detay",@"id": self.customerId,@"where":@""};

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

        self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"musteri_list"];
        for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
            ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
            customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel1"];
            customer.grubu = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"grubu"];
            customer.adres = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adres"];
            NSNumber *customerType = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"kayit_tipi"];
            /*
            if (customerType == 1) {
                customer.kayitTipi_string = @"Müşteri";
            } else if (customerType == 2) {
                customer.kayitTipi_string = @"Kişi";
            } else if (customerType == 10) {
                customer.kayitTipi_string = @"Bayi";
            } else if (customerType == 20) {
                customer.kayitTipi_string = @"Aday";
            } else {
                customer.kayitTipi_string = @"";
            }
             */
            [self.customerCards addObject:customer];

        }
        NSLog(@"Get data %@",dataDictionary);




    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

This is getDetails.

```
-(void) getDetails {
    ApiClass *customers = [self.customerCards objectEnumerator];

    //self.kayitTipi.text = customers.kayitTipi_string;
    self.Adi.text = customers.adi;
    self.faliyetAlani.text = customers.grubu;

}
```

And This is my viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"ID: %@",self.customerId);
    [self api];
    [self getDetails];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

When I start the debuging its going api method.And      `[manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {`

after this line its going the end of method.Then going to viewdidload again.And going to getdetails method.After turn back the api method.And fetching data.But its not changing anything.

Comment: You have not understood concept of success bloc properly. It don't execute in sequence like normal program. it will be called in future when your application receive response from server. but  [self getDetails]; will call before success.

Comment: Do one thing call [self getDetails]; from success block

Comment: I used    `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` after this called the getdetails in from success block but its not entering for method now